# HandlerThread multilayer post differences

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, handler

I do not really understand the difference of posting from update thread to the main thread like so:

I have this in activity's onCreate:

```
private HandlerThread updateThread;
private Handler updateHandler;
private Handler mainHandler;

public void onCreate() {
    updateThread = new HandlerThread("Update Thread");
    updateThread.start();

    updateHandler = new Handler(updateThread.getLooper());
    mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```

Then somewhere down, there is this method:

```
public void waitForRefresh(final Runnable r) {
    updateHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainHandler.post(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone explain why the `waitForRefresh` method cannot be done in this way?

```
public void waitForRefresh(final Runnable r) {
    mainHandler.post(r);
}
```

Why do we need to post to updateHandler and let it post to the mainHandler instead of posting straight to the mainHandler?

Thanks!

Comment: what will happen if you dont post it with updateHandler ??

Comment: No, it works as well... but I've seen this type of post multiple times >.<'